# ASAuthorizationController fails with existing setup flows

Tags: apple-sign-in

Apple's examples said to perform authorization attempt as soon as the login view appears using the code shown below.  When the code runs I get this non-helpful error:

> [core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7001 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=com.....SignInWithApple}

I do have something stored in the shared web credentials that it could be grabbing.  Here's the code I'm using:

```swift
private func performExistingAccountSetupFlows() {   
  let requests = [
    ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(),
    ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()
  ]

  appleSignInDelegates = SignInWithAppleDelegates(window: window)

  let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
  controller.delegate = appleSignInDelegates
  controller.presentationContextProvider = appleSignInDelegates

  controller.performRequests()
}
```

Have I missed a step here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Simulator and a real device but only when I include a request from `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run this code on a simulator.  That's what the error is saying, even though it doesn't actually *say* that.  If you run on a device it works properly.

So just wrap the code in an `#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)`

Comment: Hmmm. For me, it was working on the simulator the last several days. Now I'm getting the error as mentioned in this question.

Comment: Same for me to.  My application show this error from nothing. Don't know why now I'm getting this error.

Any one has the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
1) Tap on the Apple Sign In button
2) Swipe up (lightly just so the App doesn't switch) the white bar on the bottom of the screen.

The pop up seem to be stuck sometimes, that's why doesn't show and this error logs.

It's weird right now.

Comment: just tested on my device and this is the only thing that got it to show

Answer (score -1):

I was using [Apple's `Juice` example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/adding_the_sign_in_with_apple_flow_to_your_app) for about a week with Xcode 11 and an iPhone 8 simulator. No major problems. Then, today the issue raised in this post came up. Trying various things, what worked for me was to switch over to a different simulator-- iPhone 11. Things are working again.

Comment: check that the difference between those sims is not that the latter is one where you've signed into apple ID prior

Answer (score -2):

to try this code below

```html
func performExistingAccountSetupFlows() {
    let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()]
    // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
    
  }
```

Comment: Your code is the same as mine. You just point at yourself for the delegate. The issue is that this doesn’t work in the simulator. Works fine on a device.

Answer (score -2):

For me it started working after going to Settings ->  owners(your) account -> Password & Security -> Apple ID logins -> The app you are concerned with -> Stop using Apple ID.
This will work till you run it again from XCode, i.e. till you reinstall it. Then you got to do it again.